# ImplicitRegion evaluates the region incorrectly when it must be empty

Tags: syntax, regions, computational-geometry

Consider the following implicit region:

```
E1crit[m1_,m2_]=(m1^2+m2^2)/(2*m2);    
Cosalpha[x_, y_, cosz_] = cosz*Sin[x]*Sin[y] + Cos[x]*Cos[y];
Cosalphamin[E1_, m1_, m2_] = 
 If[E1 > E1crit[m1, m2], 
  1/(2*m2)*Sqrt[4 E1^2 m2^2 - m2^4 - 2 m2^2 m1^2 - m1^4]/
   Sqrt[E1^2 - m1^2], -1]
ymax=0.14003;
RegionX[m1_,E1_,m2_,x_]:=ImplicitRegion[Cosalpha[x, y, Cos[z]]-Cosalphamin[E1, m1, m2]>=0,{{y,0,ymax},{z,0,Pi}}]
```

This region is shrinked very fast for $E_{1}>E_{1 \text{crit}}$, and for each $E_{1},m_{1},m_{2}$ there is critical $x_{\text{crit}}$ for which the region is empty. But for $x>x_{\text{crit}}$ Mathematica fails to show the empty region:

```
RegionPlot[RegionX[6, 5*E1crit[6, 6.3], 6.3, 0.149]]
```

shows the correct region, while

```
RegionPlot[RegionX[6, 5*E1crit[6, 6.3], 6.3, 0.15]]
```

displays the errors:

```
RegionPlot::nnregion: ImplicitRegion[-0.99995+0.988771 cos(y)+0.149438 cos(z) sin(y)>=0\[And]0<=y<=0.14003\[And]0<=z<=\[Pi],{y,z}] cannot be automatically discretized.

RegionPlot::argr: RegionPlot called with 1 argument; 3 arguments are expected.
```

How to force it to set the region above the critical value to zero automatically?

Comment: `If[x > xcrit, EmptyRegion[2], ImplicitRegion[...]]`? Or use `Reduce` on the region predicate?

Comment: @MichaelE2 : xcrit is different for different E1,m1,m2. That is why I want Mathematica to do it itself.

Comment: So `Reduce` might work, then?  Or since you're doing things numerically, perhaps `DiscretizeRegion[reg, Method -> "Continuation"]` is ok? Or you can take the error as evidence that the region is probably empty.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : sorry for this stupid question, but how I have to apply Reduce?

Comment: @MichaelE2 : I will need to use this region for integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to apply `Reduce` to the predicate (= first argument) for the `ImplicitRegion`:

```
MapAt[Reduce, RegionX[6, 5*E1crit[6, 6.3], 6.3, 0.15], 1]
```

> ImplicitRegion::msgs: Evaluation of {Reduce[-0.99995+0.988771 Cos[y]+0.149438 Cos[z] Sin[y]>=0&&0<=y<=0.14003&&0<=z<=π],True} generated message(s) {Reduce::ratnz}.

```
(*  Out[]= EmptyRegion[2]  *)
```

`RegionPlot` will give an empty plot on this input.

One could manually [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the `ImplicitRegion` before passing it to `Reduce` to eliminate the warning message.

`Reduce` solves symbolically and can be slow.  One can speed it up a little by rationalizing with a larger tolerance. For example reducing `Rationalize[<region>, 1*^-8]` takes under 12s instead of under 20s.

Is that what is desired?

---

From the geometry of the inequality in the case at hand -- that is:

- `u = {Cos[x], Sin[x]}` is a unit vector (a parameter)
- `v = {Cos[y], Sin[y]}` is a unit vector (an unknown)
- `w = {vx, t*vy}`, where `{vx, vy} = v` and `t = Cos[z]` (another unknown)
- `w` lies in the segment of the unit disk where `y <= ymax`
- The inequality is that the length of the projection of `w` on `u` should be greater than a certain radius

One can see that the vertex of the segment of the unit disk where `t = Coz[z]` is equal to `1` and `y` is equal to `ymax` is the only vector `w` satisfying the inequality when `x` equals $x_{\text{crit}}$.

Then the following gives $x_{\text{crit}}$ (the larger solution):

```
NSolve[(First@RegionX[6, 5*E1crit[6, 6.3], 6.3, x] /. GreaterEqual -> Equal) &&
   0 < x < π /. {z -> 0, y -> ymax},
  x, Reals]
(*  {{x -> 0.130079}, {x -> 0.149981}}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!