# Problem with NIntegrate: it gets stuck when evaluating zero value

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

I have an integral with complicated function evaluated by MonteCarlo method (please find a folder with two files by the link below). Namely, a function `FifthDistributionOf1[m1, E1, \[Theta]2, \[Theta]1, \[Phi]2]` defined in 3.2 is integrated over the variables `\[Theta2], \[Phi2]` defined in a region `XRegionReduced[E1, m1, m2, \[Theta]1]` defined in 3.1. The resulting function is `DoubleDistributionOf1[m1, E1, method, \[Theta]1, \[CapitalDelta]\
\[Phi]1]`, where by "method" I specify the method of integration.

This resulting function is defined for $0.1 <m_{1}<5.9$,  $m_{1}< E_{1}<300$. For large $E_{1}$ and $m_{1}$ it tends to zero with increasing of `\[Theta]1` (this behavior is monotonic after reaching the maximum in `\[Theta]1`). For example, it indeed must be zero for `m1 = 5.9`, `E1=250`, `\[Theta]1 = 0.07`.

The integral `DoubleDistributionOf1[m1, E1, method, \[Theta]1, \[CapitalDelta]\
\[Phi]1]` is evaluated well if the integrand does not tend to zero in `XRegionReduced`. For example, for each value of `m1` and `E1` in the domain of definition and for `\[Theta]1<0.02`. However, it has problems with evaluating for larger values of `\[Theta]1` (specific value depends on `m1` and `E1` values) where the integral must be zero. One time it returns zero, another time it stucks, and it is not possible to predict its behavior. Examples (i.e., particular values of `E1`, `m1`, `\[Theta]1`) of such situation are in Section "Particular values of the distribution" in the end of .nb file.

Is there any way to control the evaluation of the integral in this situation? Precisely, is there any way to set it to zero dynamically instead of evaluating? The problem is that for each `E1` and `m1` there are different `\[Theta]1` for which the situation occurs, and I therefore can not set it to zero manually?

Please find a link containing .nb file with the notebook and external file which is required for evaluation of the notebook:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uUg95zj608PKLaWx--OMNfb87FInl6QJ

Comment: The code contains errors, for example, `ImplicitRegion::msgs: Evaluation of {Reduce[-0.999999+0.997551 Cos[\[Theta]2]+0.0699428 Cos[\[Phi]2] Sin[\[Theta]2]>0&&0<=\[Theta]2<=0.14003&&0<=\[Phi]2<=\[Pi]],True} generated message(s) {Reduce::ratnz}.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev : this is rather warning, which can be removed using Discretize. It seems that it does not affect the calculations.

Comment: I got zeros for Particular values of the distribution with a warning `NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 0.` and 0.` for the integral and error estimates.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev : Sometimes I also obtain zero for these values, while sometimes Mathematics stucks.

Comment: It is necessary to exclude all errors. For example, why do we need a line of code `XRegionReduced[E1_, m1_, m2_, \[Theta]1_] :=
 MapAt[Reduce, XRegion1[E1, m1, m2, \[Theta]1], 1]` ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : it is needed because NIntegrate evaluated the integral incorrectly when the region XRegion1 was empty. Please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183451/implicitregion-evaluates-the-region-incorrectly-when-it-must-be-empty for details.

Comment: replace two lines `XRegionReduced[E1_, m1_, m2_, \[Theta]1_] :=
  XRegion1[E1, m1, m2, \[Theta]1]`; `predicate2[region_] := RegionMeasure[region] < 5*10^-5`

Comment: @AlexTrounev : then the integral returns 0 even for "normal" values of E1, m1, m2...

Comment: Replace 0 with the average value of the desired function in a small area.